# Select entire section in Texstudio

Tags: texstudio, keyboard, shortcut

I am using Texstudio 2.11.0 on Arch-Linux machine. I want to know if there are any keyboard shortcut keys to

1) select entire sections/subsections?

2) jump to next section/subsection?

I could not find any in the 'Configure Texstudio' menu of the IDE.

Thanks

Comment: 1) just in left of (sub)section title you find a trinagle click on and your section will be reduced to one line (the title) you can click again back to normal mode 2) the strecture panal in the left

Comment: Ya, but that is too clumsy as I have to use mouse a lot of times.

Comment: You can do this through java scripts: menu > Macros > Edit Macros. They have default shortcuts (can be changed). For 2) there's a [user script](https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/wiki/Scripts/#finding-the-next-sectioning-command) available (you can change a couple of keywords to search backwards). For 1) you'll have to make your own script, the mentioned script gives you some clues (just keep moving the cursor keeping the anchor until you find an equal or higher ranking sectioning command (or \end{document}).

Comment: @alwaysask thanks for the hints. I am new to writing macros so

1) Can you give me link to how I can first implement the already written user script for job-2. 

2) Then i'll try to write script for job-1

Comment: Please see the manual, section 4.5.3 http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/manual/current/usermanual_en.html#SECTION33 Just copy/paste the script, give it a name, make sure it starts with `%SCRIPT` and the radio button will shift to "Script".

Answer (score 1):

Sadly I don't think there is a thing that does exactly what you want. For the navigation part of your question: you *could* just search for \section and press next or last but that's a dirty workaround. for navigating through large documents I use the ["Structure View"](http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/manual/current/usermanual_en.html#SECTION14)
Or in a case of a really long document I use documents for each chapter and include them in one main document. Another useful thing is jumping between the corresponding parts of the tex file and the pdf:

tex -> pdf: press F7 and the corresponding part in the pdf is shown

pdf -> tex: right klick->go to source code.